# Javascript Function returning wrong calculated value

Tags: javascript

Javascript

```
function freq_rate(r) {
  // Step 1 - Equivalent Effective Rate Per Frequency, m, of the Annual Rate, r
  return ((1+r)^(1/12))-1; 
}

function discount_freq_rate(r) {
  // Step 2:  The Discount Version of Step 1
  return freq_rate(r)/(1+freq_rate(r));
}

function fv(r = 0.07,n = 30 ,m = 12) {
  //Apply to a Case Where r = annual interest rate, m = # months and n = # years
  return ((1 + freq_rate(r))^(m*n)-1)/discount_freq_rate(r);
}
```

I with fv(0.07,30), I am expecting a value of 1176.06485, but I am getting "Infinity" returned.  Not sure what's wrong.  My calculations are correct in excel with the following formula:

```
C9  = 1.07^(1/12)-1
C10 =C9/(1+C9)
1176.064858 =((1+C9)^(12*30)-1)/C10
```

Comment: if you get infinity, it probably means you're trying to divide by zero in floating calculation, so `discount_freq_rate(1.07)` gives zero. Looking at freq_Rate function, you need to review the use of `^`, that's not a exponentiation (power) in javascript ! (it's bitwise-xor) Check [Math.pow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow)

Comment: `^`  in javaScript and other languages is a logical operator ( XOR operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_XOR ) not a mathematical operator

Answer (score 4):

because `^` in JS is not the "power" operator, try with this:

```
function freq_rate(r) {
  // Step 1 - Equivalent Effective Rate Per Frequency, m, of the Annual Rate, r
  return Math.pow(1+r , 1/12)-1; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `^` in javaScript and other languages is a **logical** operator  not a mathematical operator . See here->[XOR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_XOR)

In javascript you can use [`Math.pow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow)

```js
function freq_rate(r) {
  // Step 1 - Equivalent Effective Rate Per Frequency, m, of the Annual Rate, r
  return Math.pow(1+r,1/12)-1; 
}

function discount_freq_rate(r) {
  // Step 2:  The Discount Version of Step 1
  return freq_rate(r)/(1+freq_rate(r));
}

function fv(r = 0.07,n = 30 ,m = 12) {
  //Apply to a Case Where r = annual interest rate, m = # months and n = # years
  return Math.pow(1 + freq_rate(r),(m*n)-1)/discount_freq_rate(r);
}

console.log( fv(0.07,30))
```